# ROC curve tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to plot the ROC curve of the `tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier` I trained.

The ROC curve shows different values of TPR and FPR as the discrimination threshold changes, but the discrimination threshold is always 0.5.

I can't see how to tell `LinearClassifier` to change it, or to log TPR and FPR for different threshold values.

Comment: Use `predict_proba` and do the thresholding yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to do it. I needed to add a custom metric like:

```
def recall_fn(predictions=None, labels=None, weights=None):
  recall = tf.metrics.recall_at_thresholds(labels, predictions[:,1],[0.2,0.5,0.7])
  return recall
```

Then define my metrics like:

```
with tf.variable_scope("metrics"):
   validation_metrics = {
     "recall":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=recall_fn,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.PROBABILITIES)
        }
```

and finally use them in the evaluate method call:

```
results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: chk_batch_input_fn(test_stream), 
   steps=100, metrics=validation_metrics)
```

Not exactly the ROC curve, but it's the feedback/metric I wanted.